# What is the best way to sync data into Azure from a SQL server

Tags: sql-server, azure, sql-server-2012, microsoft-sync-framework

I have a SQL 2012 database that I want to sync/replicate up into Azure.

Because we intend to use this in production we cannot use the Azure Sync tool that is currently in preview.

This needs to be near real time, and only one directional. (Only ever pushing data to Azure like a cache)

What are some recommended tools for doing this?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion:

SSDT - Sql Server Data Tools

http://thomaslarock.com/2013/01/sql-server-data-tools-why-must-life-be-so-hard/
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn266028(v=vs.103).aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/tools.aspx

Answer (score 0):

if you're using Azure SQL Database, you can have a look at SSIS, Sync Framework, etc...

the biggest challenge you'll have is not the sync, but the near real time requirement that you have.

Answer (score 0):

The best approach to this problem is to use the Sync Framework, create an agent that sits on a Worker Role in your Azure environment, and a client agent that is on your network.

Here is an end-to-end sample: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Windows-Azure-Sync-Service-60293622

Here is another option, this one uses a two-tier approach that is simpler and may be more suited to your push-only scenario: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/zkap/archive/2012/04/12/synchronize-sql-server-and-sql-azure-using-sync-framework.aspx